# verify classname in php

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a regex to check that a string only contains alpha characters [a-z] or [A-Z]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990364/how-can-i-get-a-regex-to-check-that-a-string-only-contains-alpha-characters-a-z)
>   [PHP: How to check if a string starts with a specified string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790899/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-a-specified-string)

I tried writing my own regex, but I ***suck*** at it.

`#^(AJ\_)?.*#`

The problem is, I will make a string like so: `AJ______ClassNameBlahBlahBlah` and my function returns TRUE. All I need is just `AJ_` and text after it.

```
function isAnAJMClass($classname) {
     if (preg_match('#^(AJ\_)?.*#', $classname)) {
          return TRUE;
     } else {
         return FALSE;
     }
}
```

Comment: you specified .* and an underscore is a valid character. Your rule is "starts with AJ_ and then anything". What do you want it to be?

Comment: i want `AJ_` and the text after AJ_

Comment: What is "text" for you? Like I said, `.` will match any character, so "__________fooBar" is "text". If you just want letters, use [a-z]

Comment: im looking for 1 underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
preg_match('#^(AJ\_)?.*#', $classname)
```

with this:

```
preg_match('/^AJ_[a-zA-Z]+/', $classname)
```

Here is the right regular expression you need and it says:

Match every string that starts with: AJ_ followed by letters that are lowercase or uppercase

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that there will be always `AJ_` at the start of the string, you can use [`strpos($haystack, $needle)`](http://php.net/strpos) instead of regular expressions.

```
function isAnAJMClass($classname) {
     if (strpos($classname, 'AJ_') === 0) {
          return TRUE;
     } else {
         return FALSE;
     }
}
```

The use of [`substr($str, $start, $len)`](http://php.net/substr) is also possible

```
if (substr($classname, 0, 3) === 'AJ_') {
}
```

These ways, the reader can probably read the code more quickly. Independently of the method you're using, always comment the function.