# TryParse C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain how to use TryParse in C# Visual Studio to validate some textbox. I need a function using TryParse, I have an idea but it's not working

```
public void Letra(TextBox caja)
{
   char valor;

   if(char.TryParse(caja.Text, out valor))
   {
        if (caja.TextLength>1)
        {
            caja.Text = caja.Text.Remove(caja.TextLength);
            caja.SelectionStart = caja.TextLength;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and not use caps? And what is the error are you getting?

Comment: `char` is a single character - if `caja.Text` has more than one character in it, the `TryParse` will fail.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: sorry for the caps .. well i need to  create a function to validate  some textbox i really dont understan im learning ... my question is how can i validate my texbox creating  public void function .. for example i have a textbox to insert name i need this text that does not allow numbers

Comment: by not working i mean that is not doing the right job to validate no numbers in my textbox

Comment: Why don't you create a number only textbox?

Comment: Sorry I mean a no number textbox ;) Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below.
Please note, using Javascript this could be done a lot better, but since you really want a C# function, here it is.

```
public bool isValid(TextBox caja)
           {
               string sTemp;
               if (caja != null)
               {
                   sTemp = caja.Text;
               }
               else
               {
                   return false;
               }

               if (sTemp.Length > 0)
               {
                   foreach (char cTemp in sTemp)
                   {
                       if (char.IsNumber(cTemp))
                       {
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   return false;
               }
               return true;
           }
```

Regards

Comment: var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
where input is your Textbox's text
This will return the string for you containing only letters

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Regular Expression for such type of validation. It is best practice and pretty fast-

```
Regex charOnly=new Regex("^[^0-9]$");
```

You can use it in C# as you want and if your TestBox is in web form then use   RegularExpressionValidator. You should refer [How can I get a regex to check that a string only contains alpha characters [a-z] or [A-Z]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990364/how-can-i-get-a-regex-to-check-that-a-string-only-contains-alpha-characters-a-z)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your string contains numbers with following method

```
private bool CheckIfTextContainsNumber(string TextToCheck)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(TextToCheck, @"\d");
}
```

- `\d` stands for digit (0-9) + other digits e.g. arabic

Further you code create a textbox in which you cannot type in kind of numbers by creating an EventHandler which catches the KeyPress-Event.

```
YourTextBoxControl.KeyPress += YourTextBoxControl_KeyPress;
```

Here you can check whether the char typed in is a number. If the char is a number then you set Handled to true

```
private void YourTextBoxControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar);
}
```